Detect logic 1 with 5V on 3.3V GPIO pin
I need to detect a logic 1 by applying 5V to a GPIO pin of an ESP32-C-DeVKitC-02. However, I don't think the GPIO is 5V tolerant.
My questions are:

Why can 5V already be to high for a GPIO? Doesn't it have very high resistor so it should not make any difference?

What is the easiest method to still detect this signal on the GPIO?

In the comments a voltage divider was proposed. What values would I require here? The GPIO pin is pulled to ground using a 4K7 Ohm resistor.



Voltage divider?  Where is the 5V coming from?

The ESP32 is powered via the 5V pin which are used for bistable relays. To read their states, the 5V are applied between the 2nd contact of the relays.

Better draw a schematic so we know exactly how it's hooked up.

A simple 3.3V-5V logic level shifter is a good solution. About a buck and it will shift the 5v signal to 3.3v and vice-versa. Take your pick 3.3V-5V logic level shifter - amazon (also available everywhere else - sparkfun, adafruit, etc..)

Is this available in a very small format? I do not have much space left unfortunately.

The are about the size of a nickle ~ 1.5x1.5 cm.

That's a large level shifter! Or it has a lot of pins. You can get single port translators in SC70, thats 2.0mm x 2.1mm.

@DavidC.Rankin That level shifter is totally excessive for the job, even if it did function. There's plenty of other, more suitable methods for the task at hand, detecting status of bistable relays. One can wonder though, why the relays are wired like that, as the solution would be even simpler if the 2nd set of contacts would toggle 3V3 or Ground instead of 5V.

If you're using the second contact to sense the position of the bistable relay, then why not connect this contact to 3V3 so you don't have to level shift?

@Justme the size constraint may make it a good choice. From the comments I gather he is space critical. Depending on what he has, full size resistors and/or transistor will take up the same amount and more. Up to him. A divider works so long as voltages and currents are stable. I'm not advocating one is better than the other, but for simple, the shifter is hard to beat - there you are just letting somebody else worry with resistor/chip selection and surface mount it all on a nice tight board for you. Otherwise, it's up to you to do the same thing with what you have -- if you have it available.

@DavidC.Rankin The problem is that level shifter is intended for open drain comms level shifting. It can't even level shift properly if the relay simply provides 5V or disconnects from 5V, so unless you provide an answer how exactly you would use and connect that level to perform the task, I'd say two resistors is a better solution that actually can do the task.



Why can 5V already be to high for a GPIO? Doesn't it have very high resistor so it should not make any difference?


You answered that one yourself:

However, I don't think the GPIO is 5V tolerant.

The data sheet linked on the linked web page confirms this assumption in table 8 on page 14:

VIH (High-level input voltage) Max = VDD + 0.3 V.




What is the easiest method to still detect this signal on the GPIO?


Since the frequency of your signal is quite low, as relays switch in several milliseconds, you can use a simple voltage divider. The resistor can be really small in SMD.



In the comments a voltage divider was proposed. What values would I require here? The GPIO pin is pulled to ground using a 4K7 Ohm resistor.


Looking at the board's schematic on the linked web page, I presume you added that pull-down yourself. Anyway, then you need only a series resistor \$R_1\$ as in this schematic, and \$R_2\$ is your pull-down (image and formula copied from the Wikipedia page about voltage divider):

The formula solved for \$R_1\$ gives \$R_1 = R_2 \cdot ({V_{in} \over V_{out}}  - 1) = 4.7 k\Omega \cdot ({{5.5 V} \over {3.3 V}} - 1) = 3.1 k\Omega\$.
You can take a slightly higher value from the E series, for example 3.3 kΩ. This will lower the resulting voltage a bit, but it will still be above the minimum voltage to detect high (the calculation is left as an exercise to the reader).


5V is generally too much for a standard non-5V tolerant IO pin. IO pins are not "high impedance" outside the chip supplies, there are protection diodes that try to protect the pins from ESD and try to clamp IO pin with a diode to 3.3V supply. There is no "very high" resistor anywhere. Especially not in series with the IO pin to prevent 5V from getting clamped to 3.3V supply, and possibly making the 3.3V supply to rise to about 4.5V, damaging everything on board that did not tolerate 4.5V on a 3.3V supply.

Easiest (but not best) method is to put something like a 10k resistor between IO pin and 5V. The protection diodes still try to clamp less than 0.2mA to 3.3V, it might work for you. I do not recommend this as it is technically incorrect to put any stress deliberately to the protection diodes, it's what hobbyists and cheap chinese devices do because they do not care if the design is poor and takes shortcuts in circuit reliability vs circuit cost.

Voltage divider is by far the best method used by many chips and chip vendors as a method to detect USB 5V supply presence with a 3.3V IO pin. Use any values you want. All you need to know is you need to divide down 5V to 3.3V and you seem to already know that you have a 4k7 resistor from 3.3V to GND. Use pen and paper to draw and calculate it. I would like to recommend higher value than 4k7 though, but there is always a balance between loading the 5V enough or too much, and how much current leaks into unpowered MCU pin through protection diodes.



Use a bi-directional level translator or a level shifter to convert the 5V signal to 3.3V.Check the maximum clock speed of the level shifter IC. Some  support speeds only upto 6 MHz and some may support a clock speed of 50 MHz.
See the application notes below:
https://www.digikey.com.mx/Site/Global/Layouts/DownloadPdf.ashx?pdfUrl=1FA20885A8EC40B288ECFBCB8C39C267
https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN1159.pdf
You can also do a voltage divider type implementation for low clock speeds. This however introduces distortion at higher frequencies.

It's level shifting the state of a relay, so the speed is like 0.00001 MHz, max.

That frequency is about 100 Hz. For low speeds, a voltage divider type circuit may suffice.. What does your signal look like? A level translator would not introduce distortion.

Using specialized level shifter ICs just for detecting relay contacts being open or closed is not a very good solution.

For low frequency signals, a voltage divider might be sufficient. The author of the question didn't say it was for a relay operation.
